# Error in Breadcrumb: "A value for the item field is required"

Tags: schema.org, breadcrumbs, google-rich-snippets

Trying to show breadcrumb using this code:

```html
<ul itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" class="breadcrumb">
        <li>
            You are here: &#160;
        </li>

        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
                                    <a itemprop="item" href="/" class="pathway"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a>

                                    <span class="divider">
                        <img src="/media/system/images/arrow.png" alt="" />                 </span>
                                <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
        </li>
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
                                    <a itemprop="item" href="/index.php?option=com_easydiscuss&amp;view=index&amp;category_id=0&amp;Itemid=12" class="pathway"><span itemprop="name">Forum Q &amp; A</span></a>

                                    <span class="divider">
                        <img src="/media/system/images/arrow.png" alt="" />                 </span>
                                <meta itemprop="position" content="2">
        </li>
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
                                    <a itemprop="item" href="/index.php?option=com_easydiscuss&amp;view=forums&amp;category_id=18&amp;Itemid=12" class="pathway"><span itemprop="name">Service</span></a>

                                    <span class="divider">
                        <img src="/media/system/images/arrow.png" alt="" />                 </span>
                                <meta itemprop="position" content="3">
        </li>
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem" class="active">
                <span itemprop="name">
                    Excessive Misting               </span>
                <meta itemprop="position" content="4">
        </li>
</ul>
```

But when checking on Google structured data testing tool getting error item:

> A value for the item field is required.

Anyone guide on how to solve as earlier a year back it was showing incorrectly but not now.

Answer (score 0):

The last entry in your list is missing the item property which should be the URL for the page it references.

I suspect the last one is the page itself, which is not needed in the list anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, we found the same error message which seemed to be because the referred URL was not available to the tool (it was inside our company network but not publicly available). 
Pointing to a public valid URL fixed the error message on our side.